# SSH logins (non-root) on new install of FreeBSD

Tags: ssh, login, freebsd

I'm setting up FreeBSD (12 Current) on a 512 MB Pi 1 - I've got it up and running and I have a login prompt on the monitor, but there aren't any wired keyboards in this part of the world...

So, I figured I'd try connecting via ssh. I can connect but, using the [documented username/password of raspberry and raspberry](https://www.freebsdfoundation.org/freebsd/how-to-guides/installing-freebsd-for-raspberry-pi/), I'm unable to login. Is it possible that ssh logins are not enabled? Or maybe the credentials have changed?

Comment: Added link to source of the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here's what I learned...

1. sshd is enabled by default.
2. The default login credentials of raspberry/raspberry, given in the [FreeBSD Foundation HowTo](https://www.freebsdfoundation.org/freebsd/how-to-guides/installing-freebsd-for-raspberry-pi/), appear to have changed.
3. It the [install instructions on the FreeBSD wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi) an update from 2015-06-26 shows the default login and password as freebsd and freebsd.
4. The default root password is listed there as root.